# How to call a method with a delay?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In useeffect, I want to call a service several times..But because the service has a rate limit, I can not do this at the same time .How can I set the request to be sent to the api every two seconds?
This is what I have :

```
 useEffect(() => {
         getRegionsByParentId(null ,regionType.Continent);
         getRegionsByParentId(ContinentId ,regionType.Country);
         getRegionsByParentId(CountryId,regionType.Province);
         getRegionsByParentId(ProvinceId ,regionType.City);
         getRegionsByParentId(CityId ,regionType.Section);
   
  }, [props.data]);
```

What I want to do is to call `getRegionsByParentId(null ,regionType.Continent);`first, then  `getRegionsByParentId(ContinentId ,regionType.Country);`after two seconds, and so on.

Comment: You could use `setTimeout` with 2 seconds delay between each call.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please check this out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using setTimeout, a for loop and [computed property names](https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/):

```
let multiArray = [[null, 'Continent' ],
[ ContinentId  , 'Country' ],
[ CountryId , 'Province'],
[ ProvinceId  , 'City' ],
[ CityId  , 'Section' ]
];

for(let i = 0 ; i <  multiArray.length; i++){
setTimeout(()=> { getRegionsByParentId(multiArray[i][0], regionType[multiArray[i][1]]); },i*2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getRegionsByParentId(null, regionType.Continent); // Starts instantly
         
    setTimeout(() => {
        getRegionsByParentId(ContinentId, regionType.Country);
    }, 2000); // starts 2000ms later = 2seconds later
         
    setTimeout(() => {
        getRegionsByParentId(CountryId, regionType.Province);
    }, 4000); // starts 4000ms later = 4seconds later
         
    // etc....
   
}, [props.data]);
```